# Show only onfollow softwares in library SQL Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a little problem with my first Ruby on Rails app.

I have 3 tables (Software, User and Library), a user can follow a software and see its follows in his library. But i want to see only no follows in his library.

I have no problem to see the follow but when I want to see only the softwares not followed by USER, i can not do it ...

```
Software.left_outer_joins(:libraries).where(libraries: {software_id: nil})
```

This code shows me all software that does not follow, but I need this information BY USER.

And this show follow softwares

```
@library_softwares = current_user.library_additions
```

With index.html

```
<% if @library_softwares.exists? %>
...
<%end>
```

Do you have an idea ?

Sorry for my english 
Thx

**EDIT :**
I would like to reach this result:

```
@library_softwares = current_user.library_additions

@software = Software.all

@result = @software - @library_softwares
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood what you want, saves the software information in a variable

```
@softwares = Software.left_outer_joins(:libraries).where(libraries: {software_id: nil})
```

and if you have a relationship between the user and the softawre you can get user information simply by going through the array of @softwares

```
<% unless @softwares.nil? %>
  <% @softwares.each do |software| %>
    <% software.user %>
  <%end %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply !
I was not very precise in my question, I already saved the values in a variable.

I did the relationship between the user and the software, however:

<% unless @softwares.nil? %>
  <% @softwares.each do |software| %>
    <% software.user %>
  <%end %>
<%end%>

This result returns the software unfollow taking into account all the users.
But I would like only the unfollow of specific to each user.

Thx for you help